# Prevent table body from going beyond visible height of screen then add scrollbar

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table on a page.  Sometimes it will have 10 rows, and other times it will have over 100 rows.  I'd like the table to go all the way down to the bottom of the screen if there are enough rows but not past that.  I want it to add a scrollbar for just the tbody if there are enough rows to go beyond the height of the screen.  I don't want a scrollbar for the page just the tbody if necessary.  I also want the thead to always be visible at the top.

Here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/65o2bxfy/ This is mostly what I want, but I'd like it to fill to the bottom and always have the thead visible.

I also have to use table-layout: fixed on my table so that column widths are the right size.

In other places I have seen this code, but it won't work for me because I don't know the height in advance just that I want it to fill up the screen.

```
table {
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```css
table {
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div></div>
<div><table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>COL 1</th>
    <th>COL 2</th>
    <th>COL 3</th>
    <th>COL 4</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>Text col 1</td>
    <td>Text col 2</td>
    <td>Text col 3</td>
    <td>Text col 4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: like  this http://jsfiddle.net/65o2bxfy/2/ ?

Comment: `height: 100vh;`
Or if you have margin paddings, a header etc. `height: calc(100vh - 100px);`

Comment: Making the thead stay on top, is not possible using a table. Unless using some javascript (lot's of plugins available).

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha That example doesn't go all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Simsteve7 The calc(100vh - 100px) is what I was looking for.  I just now need to find a way to handle the header if it's not possible using a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS viewport units. 1 `vh` connotes 1/100th of the height of your viewport (same with `vw` for width). `min-height: 100vh` should do the trick.

```
table {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Browser support is good for it too https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

However, this solution only works if you have no other elements on your page and you're happy for it to sit at 100% tall. You could use `calc()` to offset the difference from other elements heights but then you're relying on those elements to have fixed heights.

If you're able to provide me more context as to where you want your tables to sit on your page I may be able to help you out a bit better.

To keep your the header of your table sticky set the `th` cells with a position of `sticky`.

```
thead th { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
}
```

Browser support is more sparse for that but good enough for production.

https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky